# "Хмели-сунели" и "хачапури"

Tags: род

На основании чего эти слова относятся к среднему роду согласно словарям, а не к мужскому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По обычаю древнерусскому (где жить никак нельзя без шампанского):

***большинство неодушевлённых несклоняемых существительных относится к среднему роду независимо от значения и конечной согласной***.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё о роде имён существительных [**тутъ**](http://www.licey.net/russian/culture/2_2_1).

---

P. S. По мотивам комментария...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Не пойму только, как раньше звучала "такса" мужского рода. :))

Comment: Такса (собачоночко). Происходит от нем. Dachshund «такса» (букв. барсучья собака). Но был и "такс" - барсук! (Хочу дать занимательную статейку - добавлю в ответ, сюда не знаю как.)

Comment: Спасибо за статью, Галина, очень интересно!)

Comment: Артёмчик, ещё что-нито спросите! ))) Вас, я вижу, мало травмируют мои прогулки на обочину "нормативного" стиля общения, принятого меж незнакомцами.

Comment: Конечно, нет, я даже не замечаю ничего.) Если Вы так и делаете, то очень элегантно. ;)

Comment: А кто-то жуть как покороблен: оскорблено его чувство эстетического: "Галина, а откуда такие странные эмоции: "своровано отсель". Думаю, что это не тот стиль, который можно позволить себе на этом ресурсе... эта трактовка "своровано отсель" мне кажется нелепой, неожиданной, не соответствующей действительности, да и просто оскорбительной".

Comment: Я видел это, только там то ли что-то было удалено, то ли ещё что-то, и я не понял, к чему это. Точнее, я видел, что кто-то цитировал Вас, а самих Ваших слов не видел.

Comment: Была статья картинкой, много неохваченного осталось, но уже не совсем по теме, потому и возникла кликабельная подпись "Своровано отсель". Чем шокировала и травмировала.

Comment: Мне нравится такой юмор тоже. :))